# Insert a string on regex match in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

```
str = "This website is <a href='www.google.com'>Google</a>, some other website is <a href='www.facebook.com'>Facebook</a>"
style_to_add = "style='text-decoration:none;'"
```

I want to add the `style_to_add` string to every hyperlink. So the result becomes

```
str = "This website is <a href='www.google.com' style='text-decoration:none;>Google</a>, some other website is <a href='www.facebook.com' style='text-decoration:none;>Facebook</a>"
```

Comment: `str.gsub(/(<a\b[^>]*)>/, "$1 style='text-decoration:none;'>")`

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will work

```
(href='[^']+')
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/oG9iD1/1)

More accurate regex will be to use

```
(\bhref='[>']+)>
```

*Ruby Code*

```
pattern = %r{(href='[^']+')}
str = "This website is <a href='www.google.com'>Google</a>, some other website is <a href='www.facebook.com'>Facebook</a>"
style_to_add = "style='text-decoration:none;'"
print str.gsub(pattern, '\1 ' + style_to_add)
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/s6mh7u)**